# Setting Min SDK Version causes app to function improperly: running out of memory

Tags: android, memory, sdk, version

I was getting ready to publish an app, but when I set the min SDK version to anything higher than 3, parts of my app stop working. Specifically I have buttons that launch a new activity, each with different parameters, but only one of them launches the activity if the Min SDK is set (to something other than 1).  What am I doing wrong here?  I don't think I'm missing any permissions, as the app is relatively simple.

Edit: I was looking at LogCat, and I realized that there seems to be an out of memory issue.  Each of the buttons that launches the new activity tells it to load a certain set of images to be displayed, the one button that still functions loads less images.  Is there any way to make the app function again without making the images lower quality?  Also, why does changing the min SDK version affect this?

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head as to why this would happen - but maybe there's something in the code, so can you give us an example of the one that works and one of the ones that don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing, always, to do is to look at what is being printed in logcat.  Very likely there will be error messages there telling you what is going on.

This is a rough documentation on how the various min (actually target) SDK levels modify how the platform behaves for your app: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Unfortunately there are probably a few things missing from it, but most of the major differences of interest are there.

Comment: I figured out I was improperly loading/caching the images where I didn't need to, which was taking up loads of valuable memory.  I'd still like to know why it worked for SDK versions of 3 or less, though...